# MySQL rows_examined larger than database size

Tags: mysql, optimization

I have a fairly simple query that returns a result from two joined tables. The query is run frequently and recently I've been seeing a handful of very slow excecutions. I examined my `slow_log` and was able to pull out the following information:

```
# Time: 190307 12:10:47
# User@Host: root[root] @  [XX.XX.XX.XXX]  Id: 12781339
# Query_time: 7.782994  Lock_time: 0.000049 Rows_sent: 51  Rows_examined: 909185
SET timestamp=1551960647;
SELECT 
     sg.id, 
     s.id as setting_id,
     s.data_type, 
     s.setting_type, 
     s.name, 
     (case 
       when s.data_type = 'enum' AND sg.id then 1 
       when s.data_type = 'boolean' AND sg.value = '1' then 1 
      else 0 end) as enabled, 
      sg.value 
   FROM settings s 
   LEFT JOIN settings_values sg ON s.id = sg.setting_id AND sg.merchant_id = '1588' AND sg.branch_id IS NULL;
```

What's confusing is that the two tables are far smaller than the number of rows_examined. `settings` contains only 51 rows and `settings_values` contains < 20,000 rows. Interestingly if you multiply them out, you get roughly the `rows_examined` number.

Most of the time when this query runs it excecutes in under 0.001 sec. I have replicated the queries on my local environment and when the query runs locally the `rows_examined` is 51 as expected with all other variables the same (except perhaps traffic volume). So I believe that this is only happening sometimes.

My question is, can anyone explain why the rows_examined is greater than the contents of both tables?

Also is there something obvious that would be causing this behaviour to happen erratically?

Extra info:

It's important that the result returns 51 rows all the time which is why the JOIN is the way it be. i.e. sometimes a value doesn't exist in `settings_values`, so I need to return default data.

Here's some CREATE statements for the two tables explaining indexes etc.

```
CREATE TABLE `settings` (
  `id` int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `data_type` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `setting_type` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `name` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=0 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE `settings_values` (
  `id` int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `merchant_id` int(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `branch_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `setting_id` int(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `value` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `merchant_id` (`group_id`),
  KEY `setting_id` (`setting_id`),
  KEY `branch_id` (`branch_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `settings_values_settings_FK` FOREIGN KEY (`setting_id`) REFERENCES `settings` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

EDIT:

When I run an EXPLAIN statement on my query I get the following result:

```
+----+-------------+-------+------+-------------------------------+-----------+---------+-------+------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table | type |         possible_keys         |    key    | key_len |  ref  | rows |    Extra    |
+----+-------------+-------+------+-------------------------------+-----------+---------+-------+------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | s     | ALL  |                               |           |         |       |   51 |             |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | sg    | ref  | group_id,setting_id,branch_id | branch_id |       5 | const |   25 | Using where |
+----+-------------+-------+------+-------------------------------+-----------+---------+-------+------+-------------+
```

Comment: "Interestingly if you multiply them out, you get roughly the rows_examined number." - That's what you get, if no index can support the join.

Comment: try doing an explain of the query and post the result

Comment: Sorry yeah I should have said, I've done an explain and the explain is only examining 51 and 25 rows. But I spotted a number of SO questions related to why this can differ from the rows_examined... added to question.

Comment: What is the result of `select count(*) from settings_values where branch_id = 1588`?

Comment: @PaulSpiegel result is 47

Comment: Hmm.. I don't know why this query should be slow. But an optimal index for this query would be `(setting_id, merchant_id, branch_id)` (columns in any order). It would cover all join conditions.

Comment: I actually have an index on all of those already which is doubly wierd. I am wondering though that given I'm not using a WHERE constraint (many ANDs on the JOIN instead), I could append the query with `WHERE s.id > 0` - this at least gives me an explain statement with KEYS populated for the settings table (NULL fields in row 1 of EXPLAIN result). Whether that makes a difference I'm not sure...

Comment: Wait.. there is no `merchant_id` in `settings_values` - How is it possibl that the query didn't fail?

Comment: Sorry Paul, I edited the query slightly from my real application for legibility and forgot to change that part - I've updated it now (basically group = merchant)

Comment: Note that multiple indexes on single columns do not replace a composite/combined index. The engine can only use one index per table ("index merge" is an exception which is rarely a help).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/189668/discussion-between-contool-and-paul-spiegel).